# Animation and animator android

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I'm trying to create a fragemnt that can animate - flip/rotate.
I found the start here : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

 But now I want another animation - from top to bottom but I dont understand how those `objectAnimator` work.
From how I saw the other animations worked I tried creating the top to bottom animation like this :
up_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationX"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

up_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationX"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

What I get from this animation is the right motion, but in the middle it suddenly dissappear for a moment.
I want to understand why this doesnt work, and in general how the objectAnimator works.